# Web navigation in regards to using the back button

Tags: php, html, http

I've tried to research the problem, but have had no luck finding out how to handle this. Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Consider I have three scripts to work with: homepage.php, list.php, form.php.

Conceptually, from the homepage, the user will indicate that they want to view a list. The user can then click on elements of the list, to bring up a form allowing them to alter attributes of the list item. The user submits the form and is returned back to the list, so that they can continue to view the list and make changes to the list items if needed.

Now here is the problem, when the user hits back a this point, I want them to return to the homepage, since they are currently viewing the list, and in the context of the web app, going backwards at this point should return the user to the homepage. Instead, if they hit back they go back to the form (PRG is used so no problems with double post), and then back to the list, and then back to the homepage.

**Currently what happens:**

- openbrowser   -> Get homepage.php
- homepage.php  -> GET list.php
- list.php      -> GET form.php
- form.php      -> PRG (POST to form.php, Redirect back to list.php)
- list.php      -> user hits back, GET form.php
- form.php      -> user hits back, GET list.php
- list.php      -> user hits back, GET homepage.php

**What I want to happen, but don't know how:**

- openbrowser   -> Get homepage.php
- homepage.php  -> GET list.php
- list.php      -> GET form.php
- form.php      -> PRG (POST to form.php, Redirect back to list.php)
- list.php      -> user hits back, GET homepage.php

Comment: Why don't you use js/AJAX for the form, then browser history will be a non question...

Comment: Please keep in mind, that the used does not exspect such a behaviour, he/she maybe gets confused

Comment: you can use the HTML5 history modification APIs to achieve this behavior

Answer (score 0):

```
header("Expires: Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT");
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", FALSE);
```

You can use this header in those pages in which you don't want browser to cache so that you can have a control over when user hits the back button.

In your case you can have this header on form.php and you can use session or HTTP referrer or anything to track from where is page is coming and redirect accordingly